# Enable API in Professional Edition by Managed Package from AppExchange

Tags: soap, limits, appexchange, professional-edition

I have released an App on AppExchange. I am able to install that App on my Professional Edition but API is not enabled by defualt in PE. I read one [article](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm) that shows , I can enable that with Manged Package by just passing ClientID to SOAP Header ( I uses SOAP API not REST).

Is the ClientID is the ConsumerKey when we Implement OAuth ? (ConnectedApp) or do I need to include ConnectedApp in my managed Package ?

Please Suggest how can I enable API in PE Without buying them.

Comment: Can you please share the link? I dont think that on PE api are enabled unless customer pay SFDC for it.

Comment: Starting on page 41 of this doc: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SOAP based Web services can be enabled using an API token called a Client ID"

You should work with salesforce to obtain this token for your app

Per sfdcfox's comment below:

"You have to become an ISV partner, at which point you'll be issued a client ID. You'd want to start at the Partner with the cloud leader page"

Comment: You have to become an ISV partner, at which point you'll be issued a client ID. You'd want to start at the [Partner with the cloud leader](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/overview/) page.

Comment: I have done that, I open a case and they provide me ClientID and then I have added that ClientID to my SOAP Header. Thats it. Thannk you guys.